# Calculate the Case age based on changed status

Tags: formula-field

I need to create a formula field(s) to show case age as below:

Expected outcome :

**Case Age before Case Closure**: Case Creation Date and Time - Current Date and Time = 4 hours

**Case Age after Case Closure**: Case Creation Date and Time - Case Status updated to “Closed” at = 24 hours.

**Case Age after Case Re-Opening**: Case Creation Date and Time - Case Status updated to “Re-opened” at.

**Case Age after Case Re-Closure**: Case Creation Date and Time - Case Status updated to “Re-Closed” at.

Shall I create multiple customs fields to track the age on each status? or is their a way I can Do it using only one field ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, this is a "do my work for me" question and it will likely be closed fairly quickly. You need to [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and point to a specific thing that you're stuck on. You're not going to improve if you don't put in the effort to try. If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the advise @DerekF. I'm not looking for someone to do the work for me I just need a hand to know the best way to timestamp the case age rather than creating multiple fields and then use App builder to filter those fields based on status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this with **IF(ISNULL**  Function as below :

```
IF(
    ISNULL(ClosedDate),
    TEXT(FLOOR(NOW() - CreatedDate)) & " Days " 
        & TEXT(FLOOR(MOD((NOW() - CreatedDate) * 24, 24))) & " Hours "
        & TEXT(ROUND(MOD((NOW() - CreatedDate) * 1440, 60), 0)) & " Minutes ",

    IF(
        ISNULL(Reopened_Date__c),
        TEXT(FLOOR(ClosedDate - CreatedDate)) & " Days "
            & TEXT(FLOOR(MOD((ClosedDate - CreatedDate)* 24, 24))) & " Hours "
            & TEXT(ROUND(MOD((ClosedDate - CreatedDate) * 1440, 60), 0)) & " Minutes ",

        TEXT(FLOOR(Reopened_Date__c - CreatedDate)) & " Days "
            & TEXT(FLOOR(MOD((Reopened_Date__c - CreatedDate) * 24, 24))) & " Hours " 
            & TEXT(ROUND(MOD((Reopened_Date__c - CreatedDate) * 1440, 60), 0)) & " Minutes "
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a formula isn't going to work for you here, so a single field isn't going to support this requirement. I've managed this in one of two ways before:

1. As you've noted in your question, using individual fields for each of the date/time stamps or case ages that you need to track with status updates. You then update these based using a Record Triggered Flow whenever the Case is updated to the appropriate status. This works well for relatively simple Case workflows, and where you don't expect the Case to go through the same statuses multiple times. It doesn't work well if you have a large number of status updates to time stamp OR the is the possibility of the Case going back and forward between statuses as the field values will get overwritten.
2. A more robust way is to use a Custom Object to track the status updates and when they occur. This is largely the same as the first option, but instead of updating the Case itself you create a record with the timestamp/age, and any other information that is relevant such as the new and old statuses. This allows the tracking of the Case through multiple updates to the same status but does add complexity and consumes data storage.

Comment: thank you @callum